# How do I edit "PersonalTitle" field in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I want to edit a user's "personalTitle" field in Active Directory, but cannot find where it is stored in "Active Directory Users and Computers".

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

RB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I used the ADSIEdit.msc snap-in to edit the user's personalTitle property.

This can be started using Start-> Run -> "AdsiEdit.msc"

Answer (score 4):

[**This page**](http://www.kouti.com/scripts.htm) contains a [**link to a script**](http://www.kouti.com/samplescripts/bonus/employeeID.vbs.txt) which shows you how to modify the attributes of a user. In the given example it is the `employeeId`. But it should not be difficult exchange it with the personal title property.

Look for "Bonus Material" and "employeeID.vbs".

> This script enables you to modify the employeeID attribute of a user.
>
> 1. Using ADSI Edit, locate the user-Display object (in CN=409, CN=DisplaySpecifiers, CN=Configuration).
> 2. Select the adminContextMenu attribute. Add to the attribute the value "2, Employee &ID, c:\test\employeeid.vbs" (without quotes). Do not remove the existing values, and if number 2 is already in use, select a free number.
> 3. On the computer, where you will test or use ADUC, create the file c:\test\employeeid.vbs and add the lines from employeeID.vbs.
> 4. Start ADUC and right-click any user object, and you should see "Employee ID" in the context menu.

In the script change

```
 GetObject("LDAP://schema/employeeID")
```

to

```
 GetObject("LDAP://schema/personalTitle")
```

*and*

```
 objUser.employeeID
```

to

```
 objUser.personalTitle
```

This procedure is for creating a context menu for the user. If you just want to change the value, you could do that using [ADSIEdit.msc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354.aspx). It is one of Windows Server 2003's support tools. You can download ADSI Edit [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892777), if it is not installed on your server.

Answer (score 3):

If you have heard of Powershell, and the QuestAD addon pack, the two of them make it kind of easy. To look at someones title:

```
    connect-qadservice
    (get-qaduser 'bobsusername').personalTitle
```

To set a title:

```
    connect-qadservice
    set-qaduser 'bobsusername' -personalTitle "Lord"
```

Comment: I've used PowerShell, but had never heard of the QuestAD addon. Will definitely look into that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but why go to the effort and risk of adding new attributes when there are other attributes which may be able to do the same thing, such as info, title, description or if you have MS Exchange extensionAttribute*

Comment: I think personalTitle *is* a default AD attribute - it's just not opened up by the GUI.

The specific reason we are using it is that we have a piece of software which uses it. We are looking to get the "displayName" used instead, but in the meantime...